# Phone.PHOTO_URI to real path

Tags: android

I'm using following code to get phone contact

```
Cursor phones = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{id}, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC");
if (phones != null && phones.getCount() > 0) {
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String photoUri = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
    }
}
```

Here I'm getting `content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/17` as photoUri, But I need real path, I've tried following way.

```
public static String getPath(Uri contentUri, Context context) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentUri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

But it throws `IllegalArgumentException at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel`

Comment: you should use your `Uri` (in your case `content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/17`) and not any "file path"

Comment: I want to get the profile image path, because I need to share it.

Comment: Try this syntax : `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);`

Comment: I got exception from `Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);` itself.

Comment: so share your `Uri` - not any "file path"

Comment: Oh... then is it possible to get the image name from Uri instead of file path. like `picture.png`?

Comment: @pskink I'm getting IllegalArgumentException at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel